# How can I remove a voice over translation from a movie in Media Player Classic?

Tags: windows-xp, media-player-classic

On Windows XP Professional, SP3, how can I remove a voice over translation from a movie in Media Player Classic?

The movie is in .avi format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what is decoding the AVI's audio.  Try right clicking on the video and scroll to audio and choose.

If you are using ffdshow or the like, then you'll need to find their options.

Or it could just be that the audio you are hearing is the only audio in the file.

Comment: +1 plus accept!  Fantastic. 2nd audio stream. English only. Thanks a lot.